# Securing AJAX calls with a NodeJS/Express application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to handle securing AJAX calls in an ExpressJS app?

I have a Jade template which references an external JavaScript file that handles posting requests to an endpoint on my server. Right now, that same endpoint can be reached without any authentication (obviously).

```
  // Sample AJAX call in my client-side JavaScript file (which dynamically updates a chart)
  $.ajax({
  url: 'https://example.com/jsonp?callback=?',
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    startDate: formatDate(fromDate, ''),
    endDate: formatDate(toDate, '')
  },
  success: function(response){
    //generateChart(processData(response));
  }
```

I know Express can pass objects/variables to Jade templates, but can Jade templates pass those to included scripts? My hunch is probably not...

Is there a modification I can make for my /jsonp endpoint in Express so that it only accepts requests from mysite.com and localhost? Embedding data in the client-side JavaScript (such as authentication credentials or an API key) seems like a poor way to go.

```
// Route definition in Express
router.get('/jsonp', function(req, res){
  var obj = {"_id": "234e62ASFsdsds", "name": "An object", "status": "READY"};
  var callbackFunction = (req.query.callback) ? req.query.callback : 'cb';
  res.send(wrapJSONP(callbackFunction, obj)); 
})
```

Or am I barking up the wrong tree and need to consider a different approach entirely?

Comment: Is the only requirement on your endpoint that it services requests from authorized users from mysite.com or localhost, without any authentication? If so, you could make the route check [`req.hostname`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.hostname) or `req.originalUrl` but that seems like it'd be easily spoofed and bypassed. I would really want to put some kind of authentication in place, so access is granted at the route level based on prior validation. I like [passwordless](https://passwordless.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If you do the endpoint as straight JSON (instead of JSONP, which is kind of designed to easily bypass cross-domain security for public APIs), the `Access-Control-*` family of headers ([CORS headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) is going to do exactly what you want. The browser itself will enforce this and prevent any AJAX requests from non-matching domains.

Specifically, you want two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers, with `http://yoursite.com` and `http://localhost` as values.

With JSONP, about the only thing you can do is look at the `Referer` header on the server-side before returning the script - but that's unreliable and easy to spoof.